# Matlab) how can I plot graphs of function with various input arguments?

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

**mfunction.m**

```
function[P] = mfunction(v,M,R,T)
P=4*pi*(M/(2*pi*R*T)).^(3/2)*v.^2*exp((-M*(v.^2))/(2*R*T));
end
```

I want to make a graph. x would be v and the range is `1: 1200`,

```
M = 0.032,R = 8.31, T= 300
```

and I want to plot `y=mfunction(x)`

and errors pop up. How can I draw a graph?

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: >>x=1:1200;


>>y=mfunction(x,4,8,100);



??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> mfunction at 2
P=4*pi*(M/(2*pi*R*T)).^(3/2)*v.^2*exp((-M*(v.^2))/(2*R*T));

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies at the middle multiplication

```
P=4*pi*(M/(2*pi*R*T)).^(3/2)*v.^2  *   exp((-M*(v.^2))/(2*R*T));
                                   ^
```

What you are doing is similar to doing

```
[1,2] * [1,2]
```

, which gives you the error "mtimes Inner matrix dimensions must agree", because it is multiplying a mx1 matrix to an mx1 matrix.

Depending on want you need, you can do one of the following:

```
>> [1,2] * [1,2]'  %inner product

ans =

     5

>> [1,2]' * [1,2]

ans =

     1     2
     2     4

>> [1,2] .* [1,2]  %element-wise product

ans =

     1     4
```